# Series representation of $1/|x-x'|$ using legendre polynomials

Tags: taylor-expansion, legendre-polynomials

Given two vectors $\mathbf x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbf x'\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume: $x = |\mathbf x|$ and $x' = |\mathbf x'|$.

Show that:
$$
\frac{1}{|\mathbf x - \mathbf x'|} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x'^2 - 2xx'\cos(\mathbf x, \mathbf x')}} = 
\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i_<}{x^{i+1}_>} P_i(\cos(\mathbf x, \mathbf x'))
$$

Where $x_>$ and $x_<$ are defined:
$$
 x_> =
   \begin{cases}
   x        & \text{if } x > x' \\
   x'       & \text{if } x < x'
  \end{cases}
\quad\quad
 x_< =
   \begin{cases}
   x        & \text{if } x < x' \\
   x'       & \text{if } x > x'
  \end{cases}
$$

and where $P_i(x)$ is the [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). A representation:
$$
P_i(x) = \frac{1}{2^i i!}\frac{d^i}{dx^i}\left(x^2-1\right)^i
$$

I think this is done using Taylor expansion. I tried but I failed. Actually, I have no clue where to begin to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taylor expansion won't get you where you wish to go.
Start with the general solution for Laplace's equation, which involves spherical harmonics:
$\Delta \Phi = 0$ solutions are $$\Phi(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-l}^l [A_{lm}r^l+B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}]N_{lm}P_{lm}(cos\theta)e^{im\phi}$$
Where $N_{lm}$ is a normalizing factor which may be absorbed into $A_{lm}$ and $B_{lm}$.

As $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^{'}}|}$ is a solution to the Laplace equation, it can be written as above. Obviously then, only $m=0$ applies. So it remains to determine $A_l$ and $B_l$ in

$$\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^{'}}|}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty[A_lr^l+B_lr^{-(l+1)}]P_{l}(cos\theta)$$

First let's look at an $\mathbf{r^{'}}$ vector along the z-axis, and also first take $\mathbf{r}$ aligned with $\mathbf{r^{'}}$, so that $\theta=0$, and (remember that $P_{l}(1)=1$ for all $l$)

$$\frac{1}{|r-r^{'}|}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty[A_lr^l+B_lr^{-(l+1)}]$$

It is also clear that

$$\frac{1}{|r-r^{'}|}=\frac{1}{r-r^{'}}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{1-\frac{r^{'}}{r}}=\frac{1}{r}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(\frac{r^{'}}{r})^l=\sum_{l=0}^\infty(r^{'})^l\cdot r^{-(l+1)}$$ when $r>r^{'}$

and

$$\frac{1}{|r-r^{'}|}=\frac{1}{r^{'}-r}=\frac{1}{r^{'}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{r}{r^{'}}}=\frac{1}{r^{'}}\sum_{l=0}^\infty(\frac{r}{r^{'}})^l=\sum_{l=0}^\infty({r^{'}})^{-(l+1)}\cdot r^l$$ when $r<r^{'}$

So the solution splits in two functions: one for $r>r^{'}$ where $A_l=0$ and $B_l=(r^{'})^l$, and one for $r<r^{'}$ where $A_l=(r^{'})^{-(l+1)}$ and $B_l=0$.

Clearly, then, for other $\mathbf{r}$ that are not aligned with $\mathbf{r^{'}}$, the values of the factors $A_l$ and $B_l$ are the same but the series expansion now includes factors $P_{l}(cos\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r^{'}}$ (which obviously is the same as the actual $\theta$, the angle between $\mathbf{r}$ and the z-axis).

Moving to $\mathbf{r^{'}}$ not along the z-axis, the same expansion will hold, as rotating both $\mathbf{r^{'}}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ in the same fashion does not change the angle between them, nor their length.

Hence

$$\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^{'}}|}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{r_{<}^l}{r_{>}^{l+1}}P_{l}(cos\theta)$$

Answer (score 1):

Relabel your vectors so that magnitudes are ordered as $x<x'$.

Let $\epsilon=x/x' <1$ be the small parameter.

Introduce normalized projection coefficient $\cos(\theta) = \alpha$ for convenience.

Let us call your expression E.

$$E =(x^2+x'^2-2xx'\alpha)^{-1/2}$$

Pull out $x'^{-1}$ and store it on the other side.

$$x'E = \left(1+\frac{x^2}{x'^2}-2\frac{x}{x'}\alpha\right)^{-1/2}= \left(1+\epsilon^2-2\alpha\epsilon\right)^{-1/2}$$

Let us call $(\epsilon^2-2\epsilon\alpha)=u$. It is clear that as $\epsilon$ decreases, $u$ decreases.

$$x'E = \left(1+u\right)^{-1/2}$$

Expand this in series.

$$x'E = 1-\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{3}{8}u^2-\frac{5}{16}u^3 \dots \mathrm{etc.} $$

Now substitute:

$$x'E = 1-\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon^2-2\epsilon\alpha) +\frac{3}{8}(\epsilon^2-2\epsilon\alpha)^2-\frac{5}{16}(\epsilon^2-2\epsilon\alpha)^3 \dots $$.

Okay. We are going to sort the series by powers of the small parameter.

Let's expand the binomials.

$$x'E = 1-\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon^2-2\epsilon\alpha) +\frac{3}{8}(\epsilon^4-4\epsilon^3\alpha+4\epsilon^2\alpha^2)-\frac{5}{16}(\epsilon^6-6\epsilon^5\alpha+12\epsilon^4\alpha^2-8\epsilon^3\alpha^3) \dots $$.

Now let's sort by powers of $\epsilon$.

$$x'E = 1+\epsilon\left(\alpha\right)+\epsilon^2\left(\frac{3}{2}\alpha^2-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\epsilon\left(\frac{5}{2}\alpha^3-\frac{3}{2}\alpha\right) \dots $$

Look carefully. These multipliers are the Legendre polynomials. This is how to generate them. You can see that they form a two separate Jacobi normal forms: one for even and one for odd. Anyways, back to the problem.

Finish by substitution:

$$E = \frac{1}{x'}\left[1+\left(\frac{x}{x'}\right)\cos(\theta)+\left(\frac{x}{x'}\right)^2\left(\frac{3}{2}\cos^2(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{x}{x'}\right)^3\left(\frac{5}{2}\cos^3(\theta)-\frac{3}{2}\cos(\theta)\right) \dots \right]$$

$$E = \frac{1}{x'} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{x'}\right)^l P_l(\cos(\theta))$$

We're done!

Note: The previous answers in this thread assumed the conclusion. My answer not only gives you the answer but also sets you well on your way to finding the Legendre equation from scratch.