# What is the value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{8})^n\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

What is the value of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)^n\binom{2n}{n}\;?$$

EDIT

I bumped into this series when inserting $\overrightarrow{r_1}=\left(\begin{array} {c}0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)$ and $\overrightarrow{r}=\left(\begin{array} {c}1\\1\\0\end{array}\right)$ into $$\frac{1}{|\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r_1}|}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{r_{<}^l}{r_{>}^{l+1}}P_{l}(cos\theta)\;.$$

See ([Series representation of $1/|x-x'|$ using legendre polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038234/series-representation-of-1-x-x-using-legendre-polynomials/1070398#1070398)).

So I knew the result, $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$, but wished to find out what other approaches there would be to evaluate the series.

It transpires that I overlooked the relatively standard evaluation of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}x^n$ as being equal to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-4x}}$, following a calculation similar to that given by achille-hui below, which requires some complex function theory, in particular when proving that $\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\right)^{2n}d\theta$, or that of alex.jordan below, requiring no more than Taylor expansion.

Comment: the result should be $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: Where did the series come from?

Comment: What's you thought on this question? Did you make any progress?

Comment: This is a [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: Lucian, the argument to the binomial coefficient is not parametrized by the sum index in the definition given on that page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in Dr. Graubner's comment, the sum is $\sqrt{\frac23}$.

In fact, this is a special case of a sort of famous Taylor series expansion:;

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} z^n$$

which appeared as limiting example of several theorems in complex analysis.

To compute the series ourselves, we can use following integral representation of 
the binomial coefficients:

$$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} (e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})^{2n} d\theta
= \frac{4^n}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2n}\theta d\theta
$$
Substitute this into our sum, we find the sum is equal to

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac12\cos^2\theta\right)^n d\theta
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+\frac12\cos^2\theta} d\theta
= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+\frac12\cos^2\theta} d\theta
$$
Introduce change of variable $t = \tan\theta$, this becomes

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2(1+t^2)}}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}
= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2 + \frac32}
= \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac23}\left[ \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac23} t \right]_0^\infty
= \sqrt{\frac23}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum\binom{2n}{n}x^n
&=\sum\frac{1}{n!}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}x^n\\
&=\sum\frac{1}{n!}2^n(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots(3)(1)x^n\\
&=\sum\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{2n-1}2\right)\left(\frac{2n-3}2\right)\cdots\left(\frac32\right)\left(\frac12\right)(4x)^n\\
&=\sum\frac{1}{n!}\left(-{\frac{2n-1}2}\right)\left(-{\frac{2n-3}2}\right)\cdots\left(-{\frac32}\right)\left(-{\frac12}\right)(-4x)^n\\
&=\sum\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(0)(-4x)^n\\
\end{align}
$$

where $f(z)=(z+1)^{-1/2}$. Now interpret as a Taylor series and evaluate at $x=-{\frac18}$ (using the corresponding $z=\frac12$).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over 8}}^{n}{2n \choose n}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> With $\ds{\mu \equiv -\,{1 \over 8}}$:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{1 \over 8}}^{n}{2n \choose n}}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z}
\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\bracks{\mu\pars{1 + z}^{2} \over z}^{n}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z}{1 \over 1 + \pars{1 + z}^{2}/\pars{8z}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=8\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{2} + 10z + 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\left. 8\,{1 \over 2z + 10}\right\vert_{\,z\ =\ 2\root{6}\ -\ 5}
={4 \over 2\root{6}}=\color{#66f}{\large\root{2 \over 3}}
\end{align}